# How to find the number of rules in an external CSS file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I will preface by saying that this is for a school assignment, though I have looked up and down and have not been able to find an answer.  I'm also not asking for the answer to the whole assignment, just a small portion.

Anyway, the assignment is relatively simple. **Create three sections of a webpage that change styles in different ways using JS.**

- The first section is to cycle through all of the styles in a CSS file.
- The second is to randomly select the styles in the file.
- The third is to use a form for the user to select the styles.

I know how many rules are in the CSS file, but I'm trying to code as if I don't.

How can I find how many rules are in the file?  Every time I try using `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules.length` I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`.

What am I doing wrong here?  What is the correct syntax for this?

EDIT:  I've attached the code for the HTML, CSS and JS.  I feel like I am missing something really simple.

```js
function cyclingStylize(){
    
    var styleRules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules.length;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < styleRules; i++){
        var myStyle = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[i];
        document.getElementById('MessageCell1').style.cssText = myStyle;
    }
    

    setTimeout("cyclingStylize()", 1500);
    return;
}
```

```css
.myStyle1  {color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:12; background-color:green}

.myStyle2  {color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:18; background-color:red}

.myStyle3  {color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:24; background-color:blue}

.myStyle4  {color:black; font-family:Arial; font-size:30; background-color:white}

.myStyle5  {color:red; font-family:Verdana; font-size:12; background-color:yellow}

.myStyle6  {color:red; font-family:Verdana; font-size:18; background-color:green}

.myStyle7  {color:red; font-family:Verdana; font-size:24; background-color:white}

.myStyle8  {color:red; font-family:Verdana; font-size:30; background-color:blue}

.myStyle9  {color:green; font-family:Courier; font-size:12; background-color:white}

.myStyle10 {color:green; font-family:Courier; font-size:18; background-color: red}

.myStyle11 {color:green; font-family:Courier; font-size:24; background-color:yellow}

.myStyle12 {color:green; font-family:Courier; font-size:30; background-color: purple}

.myStyle13 {color:blue; font-family:Times; font-size:12; background-color:yellow}

.myStyle14 {color:blue; font-family:Times; font-size:18; background-color:white}

.myStyle15 {color:blue; font-family:Times; font-size:24; background-color:red}

.myStyle16 {color:blue; font-family:Times; font-size:30; background-color:green}

.myStyle17 {color:white; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:12; background-color:black}

.myStyle18 {color:white; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:18; background-color:green}

.myStyle19 {color:white; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:24; background-color:red}

.myStyle20 {color:white; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:30; background-color:blue}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Style Viewer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="style.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body onload="cyclingStylize()">
  <table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td align="center">
     <font size="3"><b>STYLE CLASS VIEWER</b></font>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="MessageCell1" align="center" height="50" width="400" class="myStyle1">
     <div id="MessageText">
      Hello World Wide Web!
     <div>
    </div></div></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  <hr>
  <table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black">
   <tbody><tr>
    <td align="center">
     <font size="3"><b>STYLE CLASS VIEWER</b></font>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="MessageCell2" align="center" height="50" width="400" class="myStyle1">
     <div id="MessageText">
      Hello World Wide Web!
     <div>
    </div></div></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  <hr>
  <form name="StyleForm">
   <table align="center" border="0">
    <tbody><tr><td>
     <table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black">
      <tbody><tr>
       <td align="center">
        <font size="3"><b>STYLE CLASS VIEWER</b></font>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="MessageCell3" align="center" height="50" width="400" class="myStyle1">
        <div id="MessageText">
         Hello World Wide Web!
        <div>
       </div></div></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody></table>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
     <p>
      </p><h4>Select Font Color:</h4>
      <font face="Courier New">
       <input name="color" value="red" type="radio">red
       <input name="color" value="black" type="radio">black
       <input name="color" value="blue" type="radio">blue
       <input name="color" value="green" type="radio">green
       <input name="color" value="white" type="radio">white
      </font>
     <p></p>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
     <p>
      </p><h4>Select Font Family:</h4>
      <font face="Courier New">
       <input name="family" value="Arial" type="radio">Arial
       <input name="family" value="Verdana" type="radio">Verdana
       <input name="family" value="Courier" type="radio">Courier
       <input name="family" value="Times" type="radio">Times
       <input name="family" value="Helvetica" type="radio">Helvetica
      </font>
     <p></p>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
       <p>
      </p><h4>Select Font Size:</h4>
      <font face="Courier New">
          <input name="sizes" value="12" type="radio">12
          <input name="sizes" value="18" type="radio">18
          <input name="sizes" value="24" type="radio">24
          <input name="sizes" value="30" type="radio">30
      </font>
     <p></p>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
       <p>
      </p><h4>Select Background Color:</h4>
      <font face="Courier New">
       <input name="background" value="red" type="radio">red
       <input name="background" value="blue" type="radio">blue
       <input name="background" value="green" type="radio">green
       <input name="background" value="black" type="radio">black
       <input name="background" value="white" type="radio">white
      </font>
     <p></p>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
     <input type="button" value="Change Style" onclick="userStylize()">
    </td></tr>
   </tbody></table>
  </form>

 


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are sure the page has external stylesheets?

Comment: it's the correct syntax, but the `document.styleSheets` is not an object (ie no stylesheets are found)

Comment: Yes.  The external stylesheet and js file are referenced in the html file.  I've tried adding the styles in the html file and do not get an error, so it has to be something with the way the file is being referenced.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?  In case you're unaware f12 or ctrl+shift+i opens the debugger.  It should error if it could not load a CSS stylesheet.  (You can also view under the network tab what the requests returned for the stylesheets in question.)

Comment: which browser u are trying ,  IE and Firefox varies in their implementation of the CSS Rule object

Comment: @csga5000 Yes.  I've used the console.  That's how I know what the error is:  "Uncaught TypeError:  Cannot read property 'length' of null."

Comment: @SamuelCook  How is it that no stylesheets are found?

Comment: @Harlan Yes sorry, I didn't mean to demean your experience.  The network tab may still be useful (to see if the css request is present and as expected)

Comment: @SamuelCook I think if it was a problem with `document.styleSheets` then it would be an array out of bounds issue. @Harlan's error is on the `length` property of `cssRules` which means it found the the 0-indexed styleSheet then `cssRules` is the one that's undefined.

Comment: document.styleSheets is not linear, css imports branch off, so it can takes some iteration before you find "the motherload"

Answer (score 1):

`cssRules` does not have cross browser support. Meaning, some browsers will recognize that property, and some will not. There is also a `rules` property that some browsers will use. [Read more here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html).

One way to do this is through "feature detection". Something like:

```
var rules = []; //default to empty array
var firstsheet = null;

//check for any available styleSheets
if (document.styleSheets && document.styleSheets.length > 0) {
    firstsheet = document.styleSheets[0];
    //see which array is available in this browser
    rules = (firstsheet.cssRules) ? firstsheet.cssRules : firstsheet.rules;
    //^^^^^The feature detection line, detecting cssRules, and returning it or rules
}

//alert the length
alert(rules.length);
```

In  case it's not obvious, the `(boolExpression)?truePart:falsePart;` is a way in javascript to easily check an expression. In this case, putting `firstsheet.cssRules` into the parenthesis will coerce it into a boolean forcing JS to return true if the property exists, and false if it doesn't. This makes the assumption that if `cssRules` doesn't exist, then `rules` is the array to use.

Also you can put the rules request into a function:

```
function getSheetRules(sheetIndex) {
    var rules = []; //default to empty array
    var sheet = null;

    //check for any available styleSheets
    if (document.styleSheets && document.styleSheets.length > 0) {
        sheet = document.styleSheets[sheetIndex];
        //see which array is available in this browser
        rules = (sheet.cssRules) ? sheet.cssRules : sheet.rules;
    }

    return rules;
}

var rules = getSheetRules(0);

//alert the length
alert(rules.length);
```

Welcome to the joys of working with javascript in a cross browser environment.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the existance for `.rules`/`.cssRules` and use the existing one:

```
document.styleSheets[index].rules // Chrome, Firefox, Opera, modern IE

document.styleSheets[index].cssRules // old Internet Explorer
```